# How to make a window with labeled spinbox in C++ using WinAPI

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface, winapi

I've spent a day trying to make working such a simple thing as this:
[image: spinbox]
<sub>(source: [s-msft.com](https://i-msdn.sec.s-msft.com/dynimg/IC725451.png))</sub>

All i need is to be able to programmatically get value, set value, and of course allow user to set value by writing into the field or pressing the arrows.
MSDN is really messy about that and does not provide enough information how it works. In the rest of the internet there is no working example of code doing it.

- [msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh298353(v=vs.85).aspx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/create-an-up-down-control) - not compilable
- [www.drdobbs.com/creating-spin-controls-for-windows/184402858?pgno=4](https://www.drdobbs.com/creating-spin-controls-for-windows/184402858?pgno=4) - not compilable
- [forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?484588-Up-down-spin-control](https://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?484588-Up-down-spin-control) - does not work

I'm compiling the program with MinGW in Windows 7 and i need it to work on Windows 7 and above.
It does not matter, whether it will be written using procedural Win32 API or MFC.

**Edit:**
After some discussion i realized i forgot to point out important fact. I'm really writing just a very simple application, that will contain no more than 3 widgets, and i don't plan to use Win32 API for this in the future. Therefore there is no reason for me to learn all those compilicated Windows-specific mechanisms and follow the MSDN robust methods using custom dialog definitions in resource files or constructed in memory.

Is there a way, how to do it without resource files, custom dialog classes, and with as few lines of code possible? How to directly create a spinbox in an existing window and what messages do i need to handle?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What problems have you encountered? What code can you show us?

Comment: *"I'm compiling the program with MinGW"* - Why do you assume, that the MSDN were providing code samples for this tool chain? Get yourself [Visual Studio Community](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/community/), if you are still struggling with understanding compiler/linker errors.

Comment: @IInspectable: I was expecting the API will be same no matter the compiler, but apparently there are some declarations missing in MinGW `windows.h` and `commctrl.h` headers.

Comment: Vanilla MinGW has not been updated to any API after Windows 2000. If you insist on MinGW, use MinGW-w64 instead. And the next time you find example code that does not compile, and come here to ask about it, be sure to post the exact file you are trying to compile (since I assume you properly formatted the example code!) and compiler errors. That way, we can figure out what errors you made.

Comment: @andlabs: I understand what you mean, but i have tried many different ways according to many different sources, and always got stuck somewhere else. So i scrapped that all and came here to ask hoping that you will maybe point me in the right direction, that doesn't require reading a book, writing a 500 lines of code and spending 4 hours of programming.

Comment: You have the wrong expectations. If you want to write a GUI application without using any libraries, you will be writing lots of code. And you need to read a book. If you want to use MFC, you will write a little less code. But to use MFC, you need to read two books.

Comment: @andlabs: Actually in the end i just had to read the intro and selected sections of this [guide](http://zetcode.com/gui/winapi/controlsII/), it contains all needed information and shows how to write it easily on few lines. Unlike MSDN, which always tells you you need to define own dialog class in resource or construct class in memory. I'm doing a simpliest program ever and just once, there is no reason for me to learn all those mechanisms and use external tools to build such robust system in my code. Perhaps i should have put more emphasize of that in the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your parenthetical comments to the side of those links leave a bit of a sour impression in my mind. No, of course they are "not compilable." The purpose of documentation is not to give you fully written and polished code that you can simply drop into your project. [The MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh298353.aspx) is trying to get you to understand how up-down controls work, and this, armed with your background knowledge of the Win32 API, should be enough to get them working in your project.

To be fair, [the Dr. Dobbs article](http://www.drdobbs.com/creating-spin-controls-for-windows/184402858?pgno=4) you link *is* about 16-bit Windows, which is a rather different programming environment than 32-bit Windows, so this is probably not a good reference if you're not already a Win32 expert so that you can spot the differences. Some of them are subtle.

Also, I mentioned something above about "your background knowledge of the Win32 API". That's important. You need to understand Windows programming if you want to do Windows programming. It isn't something that you'll be successful at by cobbling together code samples from various places around the web. Very little programming is this way, but certainly not complex C APIs. The standard resource for learning Win32 is the 5th edition of Charles Petzold's *Programming Windows*. Since you want the 5th edition (not newer), used copies are regularly available for cheap on [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/157231995X).

Preliminaries out of the way, I'm going to take a shot at answering your question. When you say that you want to create a "window", this is somewhat ambiguous, because in the language of Windows programming, *everything* is a window. Each of these controls are actually Windows, they can be hosted on a container that is itself a window, and that container can be hosted on a dialog box or top-level window. So it is unclear to me exactly what you want the final product to look like.

I'm going to guess that you probably want a *dialog box* (which is, of course, a window) that contains these controls. Using a dialog box makes things pretty simple, because you can just use a resource editor to graphically lay out the dialog box with the controls you want. The Visual Studio programming environment comes with a built-in resource editor, but you can use a third-party solution if you like. [ResEdit](http://www.resedit.net/) and [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/) are solid choices. Of course, you'll need to read the documentation to figure out how to make these tools work for you. Ultimately, what they will do is generate a dialog template that is stored in a resource file and linked into your binary. An example dialog template looks like the following:

```
IDD_DIALOG1 DIALOGEX 0, 0, 238, 54
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_MODALFRAME | DS_FIXEDSYS | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
CAPTION "Dialog"
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 400, 0, 0x1
BEGIN
    LTEXT           "&Month:",IDC_STATIC,7,9,30,8
    EDITTEXT        IDC_MONTH,37,7,40,14,ES_AUTOHSCROLL
    CONTROL         "",IDC_MONTH_SPIN,"msctls_updown32",UDS_SETBUDDYINT | UDS_ALIGNRIGHT | UDS_AUTOBUDDY | UDS_ARROWKEYS,63,15,11,14
    LTEXT           "&Day:",IDC_STATIC,84,9,30,8
    EDITTEXT        IDC_DAY,114,7,40,14,ES_AUTOHSCROLL
    CONTROL         "",IDC_DAY_SPIN,"msctls_updown32",UDS_SETBUDDYINT | UDS_ALIGNRIGHT | UDS_AUTOBUDDY | UDS_ARROWKEYS,140,16,11,14
    LTEXT           "&Year",IDC_STATIC,161,9,30,8
    EDITTEXT        IDC_YEAR,191,7,40,14,ES_AUTOHSCROLL
    CONTROL         "",IDC_YEAR_SPIN,"msctls_updown32",UDS_SETBUDDYINT | UDS_ALIGNRIGHT | UDS_AUTOBUDDY | UDS_ARROWKEYS,217,16,11,14
    DEFPUSHBUTTON   "OK",IDOK,127,32,50,14
    PUSHBUTTON      "Cancel",IDCANCEL,181,32,50,14
END
```

Note that, as the MSDN documentation says, the Up-Down control is actually just the little spinner box. You need to attach it to a text box (Edit control) to make it useful. The spinner box will automatically buddy up with the edit control that comes before it in the Z order. This vastly simplifies the code, although you can use the APIs to manipulate the controls to achieve the same effect manually, if you like. The MSDN documentation explains how.

Once you have this dialog template defined and set to be linked into your project, you can display the dialog box with a simple call to the `DialogBox` function. In the code above, I have given the dialog box the symbolic name `IDD_DIALOG1`; this should be defined in a resource header file that is globally accessible, both to regular code and to the resource compiler.

You will also need to define a dialog procedure that will process messages for the dialog. Message processing is *far* too much for me or anyone else to explain in a simple article/answer. This is where you need to consult Petzold or some other general Win32 programming resource to fill in the gaps.

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <Windows.h>        // include Windows SDK headers
#include <commctrl.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include "resource.h"       // include resource definitions

INT_PTR CALLBACK Dialog1Proc(HWND hwndDlg, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
      case WM_INITDIALOG:
      {
           return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
      }
      case WM_COMMAND:
      {
         switch (LOWORD(wParam))
         {
            case IDOK:
            case IDCANCEL:
            {
               EndDialog(hwndDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
               return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
            }
            default:
            {
               break;
            }
         }
         break;
      }
    }
    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}

int APIENTRY _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE, LPTSTR, int nCmdShow)
{
   // Initialize the common controls at the start of your application.
   INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX iccex;
   iccex.dwSize = sizeof(iccex);
   iccex.dwICC  = ICC_WIN95_CLASSES;

    // Show the dialog box.
    // This creates a modal dialog box that runs its own message loop,
    // and thus does not require your code to have its own.
    // A modal dialog box is therefore *blocking*, and this function call
    // does not return until the dialog box has been dismissed.
    DialogBox(hInstance,   // handle to instance that contains your resources (probably your EXE)
              MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG1),
              NULL,        // handle to parent window of dialog, or NULL if no parent
              Dialog1Proc  // pointer to dialog's window procedure
             );
    return 0;
}
```

This will get the dialog box up on the screen:

[image]

But the fun has only begun! You will probably want to write code in the dialog box's window procedure to handle certain messages and control the behavior of the dialog. The up-down controls do work to change the integer value displayed in the text box, but you might want to set an acceptable range. Or you might want to reverse the max and min so that the bottom arrow decrements the value instead of incrementing it (this unusual and unexpected behavior is the default for compatibility reasons).

And if you want actually want to *retrieve* the values that the user entered into the text boxes, you have even more work ahead of you. A basic strategy is to retrieve the values in response to the `WM_DESTROY` messsage and store them somewhere where they can be read from the caller. There are, of course, better ways of doing this, and using a C++ object-oriented wrapper makes it even easier, but it is more advanced and requires some basic knowledge of how Windows programming works.

It is also worth pointing out that if you cannot use a dialog template for whatever reason, or you want to create a standard window, you can also write code that manually creates these individual windows by calling the `CreateWindowEx` function. This is what [the MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh298353.aspx) that you linked is trying to describe. It does work, and it is more flexible, but it is also more complicated. Honestly, you should be able to figure it out by reading the MSDN article. It is very complete and rather well-explained, which I'll grant isn't *always* what you see on MSDN, but this is not one of those cases.

Comment: Wow, thanks for your time. I really didn't expect anyone to write such detailed answer. Yea, the problem really is, i don't know much about programing GUI in Windows API, normaly i would use library like Qt, where things are way easier, but this time it's a specific homework, where i have to deal with pure system API.

Comment: I find Qt much more difficult to use. I suppose it's all what you get used to. If this wasn't the answer you were expecting, I'm not sure what you *were* expecting when you asked this question. Do note that Stack Overflow generally considers "recommend a tutorial" questions to be off-topic. There is a close reason specifically for that, see [number 4 here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). @youda

Comment: Sorry, i meant that you explained it better than what i hoped, not that you answered something else than what i wanted.